# How do I use XML and CSS together to make a "fancy" SiteMap?

Tags: css, xml, sitemap

I have created a sitemap that conforms to the SiteMap protocol. This is in XML format. How would i apply CSS to create a fancy site map similar to [Fraunhofer](http://www.fraunhofer.de/en/sitemap.html)?

The xml was made by an online sitemap generator, and has "url" tags. Each tag represents a page, but nothing is inside that tag except info about that page (no url tags within tags, to show a tree like setup), so how would i even show what links are level 1, 2, or 3? Also, since this format only has one main tag called "URL", i cant style different sites differently.

EDIT: This is what some of my generated XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset 
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
    http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
 >

<url>
    <loc>http://buytadiran.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-03-04T15:21:12-06:00</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://buytadiran.com/index.php?option=com_content&#x26;view=article&#x26;id=47&#x26;Itemid=54</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-03-04T15:21:12-06:00</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Id like to have a tree like set up similar to what i linked, without the folds, where a top level page is shown in green or something, and sub pages are shown indented under it with different coloring...

Is it even possible to make a sitemap that is structured this way, and still conform to the SiteMap protocol, or should i be looking at making a seperate sitemap thats "user friendly", that i'm not submitting to google?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post some generated code from this tool?

Comment: I certainly can..... it is a big site map though, and i figured mentioning that it was SiteMap Protocol compliant was enough. I will edit my post to include a snippet.

Comment: A part of this, only to see if there is any tree structure we can target with css selectors

Comment: It doesnt seem to indicate in any way how you can get to one page from another, and this is the issue. If we ADD tags to do this, i wonder if it would break protocol compliance. :(

Comment: I think you can use an XML parser to create html links and style them as you want. Or maybe XSL. A google search will help. Anyway I m not sure to answer you so let's wait someone that knows better:)